# What is the command or script text to minimize a running program using notepad

Tags: notepad

Im trying to make a script minimizes the app for example I type

`start chrome`

then i want to minimize the chrome app but how??

plz remember this is all in notepad

Comment: What do you mean "this is all in Notepad"? Are you talking about Batch?

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> START /MIN

But **chrome doesn't support that...**

can you use autohotkey?

here is the code for a .ahk file to minimize chrome

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
Run, chrome.exe
WinWait, Google Chrome
WinMinimize, Google Chrome
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).